# Wrong format for index: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: javascript, console.log

I use an api interface to send dates from a google sheet to a html form.
When you select a date then should send a PATCH method to this google sheet.
But I get this error message in the console: Wrong format for index: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'vEmWzLMH3R89ZMQF4URHK'

This is my javascript code:

```
const data = {
Datum: "Jack Doe",
  Anzahl: "10",
};

// Add one line to the sheet
fetch('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/d3abdb1d-1bdc-48e3-9096-ea050256b49a/vEmWzLMH3R89ZMQF4URHK#TGinDJ#fGi%qc29AZv5ZwcZId71STqpABWTa6I5_bf/Datum/*12.12.2020 13:00 Uhr', {
    method: "PATCH",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(
      data
    ),
  })
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: It looks like you're sending the value `vEmWzLMH3R89ZMQF4URHK` where a number is expected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [the documents](https://docs.sheet.best/#put-patch-update-rows) the index is a number i.e.

> PATCH https://sheet.best/api/sheets/cf969697-682a-40e3-bad4-d54803eeeacf/2

However, you're sending `vEmWzLMH3R89ZMQF4URHK` string instead of it